# Append a tab seperated line as a heading

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have multiple txt files in a folder and the values inside each files are tab separated. Now, i would like to add a line as a heading to all the the text files which should also be tab separated.

Could someone help me with an AWK or SED command to do this ?

```
Heading
S.NO    ITEM    QUANTITY    PRICE   CUSTOMERNAME

fruit.txt
1   mango   3   55  jack
2   Fruit   6   66  mike

vegetables.txt
1   cabbage 3   77  jackson
2   carrot  6   99  tunde
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '1i Heading' *.txt
```

Note that -i will inplace change all txt files in current folder (will add 'Heading' in first line), so if you want to experiment you can create backup folder previously.